# Nginx Unable to proxy port

Tags: azure, nginx, openam, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx as a load balancer. It is able to route the request to the designated host address, but not the port as mentioned in the upstream block. It always sends it to the default port.

I have tried a number of approaches modifing `proxy_set_header Host`, `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For`, `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP`, `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto`, `proxy_set_header Referer` etc. But nothing seems to work.

I have the Nginx server installed in Azure and trying to access VM's in the same virtual network.

Expected Behavior:
http://localhost/sites   -----> http://zzz:9081/sites (should take IP:Port into acount)
Actual Behavior:
http://localhost/sites   -----> http://zzz/sites (takes IP, but the port is 80/ default listen port).

```
  upstream alb {
      ip_hash;
      server zzz:9081;
      server zzz:9080;
    }


     server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;
            # root         /usr/share/nginx/html;


            location /sites {
               proxy_pass http://alb/sites;
               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to distribute traffics to the same server but with different port?

Comment: Yes. That is my intention. But the port never changes in the URL.